# Generic string argument is not narrowed to a string literal if it's not first

Tags: typescript

The following works as expected and we see that `arg` is a string literal:

```
const foo = <T extends string = string>(arg: T) => {};

foo('my string'); // const foo: <"my string">(arg: "my string") => void
```

But once we add another generic before the one above, the narrowing isn't happening:

```
const goo = <T extends Record<string, any>, K extends string = string>(arg: K): T => ({} as T)

goo<{}>('my string'); // const goo: <{}, string>(arg: string) => {}
```

Am I expecting TS to do something it can't do or maybe there's a workaround?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVGBTAHlbMAEwhmgCcBLMAcxTKitoD4AKAQ3JoC4YMBKFMxgBvAL4BuAFBSEIVgHIAtgE8GTGgv7SpoSLBqJ6mHPkIkYAJWyhyRNBWo0ANDHZgVzVwGlTBYqSOtPRBNGycPDDe-LxYyMKs4m6kAjKGIGjibMpqoVoSQA)

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Looks normal to me.

Comment: @Behemoth `goo` should be `const goo: <"my string">(arg: "my string") => {}`, which currently doesn't narrow the `arg` and it is left with just `string`

Comment: I want to use the string argument to index an accumulated Record, a builder pattern essentially, that allows to add named instances of type T (as in the second example).

For this to work as expected the string needs to be narrowed to the literal value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it's not possible to explicitly pass the portion of the generic arguments. You have to enter all required generics and the rest are defaulted to their default values, which is what happens with the generic parameter `K`.

The solution depends on your use cases, however, I can suggest making a factory function, which will accept the `T` and return a function that will accept the `K`:

```
const gooFactory =
  <T extends Record<string, any>>() =>
  <K extends string = string>(arg: K): T => {
    return {} as T;
  };
```

Usage:

```
const goo = gooFactory<{}>();

// const goo: <"my string">(arg: "my string") => {}
goo('my string');
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MA8AVGBTAHlbMAEwhmgCcBLMAcxTKitoD4AKAQ3JoC4YMBKFMxgBvAL4BuAFBSEIVgHIAtgE8GTGgv7SpoSLBqIAYu2BQQ5Ncikx0WPAWKkAStlDkiaCtRoAaGOxgKsxsgsjMNugA0jj4hCTqPvTeLBxcvFH8vFjhopG25NhQAK7kYKJiAaQY0raSMnrQMIZIqC0mZhYqaOKhOgD0-TCNBoi8aABEqom0E2ycPDBTaik0E2HC4lItitOrWtJAA)

Comment: This seems like a direction, thanks!